# How to Call a Javascript function in VB Script

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a java script function to do natural sorting.

But i have no idea how to call this java script and get returned value of js in HP UFT using VB Script.

```
function alphanum(a, b) {
  function chunkify(t) {
    var tz = [], x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
      var m = (i == 46 || (i >=48 && i <= 57));
      if (m !== n) {
        tz[++y] = "";
        n = m;
      }
      tz[y] += j;
    }
    return tz;
  }

  var aa = chunkify(a);
  var bb = chunkify(b);

  for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
    if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
      var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
      if (c == aa[x] && d == bb[x]) {
        return c - d;
      } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }
  return aa.length - bb.length;
}
```

Please let me know how to call js?

Answer (score 2):

I built a function to call when I need to have UFT execute some javascript; here it is:

```
Public Function MISC_ExecuteJavascript(byVal oPage, byVal sJavaScript)
   Dim JSEntry
    Set JSEntry = oPage.object.documentelement.parentnode.parentwindow          
    On Error Resume Next        
    MISC_ExecuteJavascript = JSEntry.eval(sJavaScript)      
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

You pass it the `Browser().Page()` object that you need the javascript executed on, and the actual javascript call you want executed.  The function will then execute it against the page.  Hope that helps you out